# conditional state_machine transition with external api call

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, state-machine

I am wondering what the best way to set this up. Using the state_machine gem for ruby.

Essentially I have a state machine transition that is conditional on an external API call.  Something like:

```
state_machine initial: :start do
  event :move do
    transition :start => :second, if: :external_is_cool_with_it?
    transition :start => same
  end
end
```

This works pretty good, as if the external api returns true, it goes to :second, otherwise it fails, goes to the next transition, which stays on the same state. Lets say the API call sends an email.

The only problem is I can't ask:

```
instance.can_move?
```

Because that will actually run the `if`, which calls the external API etc... so when I do something like:

```
instance.move! if instance.can_move?
```

or

```
if instance.can_move?
  puts "Moveable"
  # Form to allow state_event
end
```

It would call the external API twice (send the email twice).

So I don't think the usage of `if` is correct in this case, but I also can't really use `before/after_transition` since I need it to conditionally move to the next transition if the external call fails.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. What did you end up doing? The only thing I can think to do is use an after_transition callback where the API failure results in another transition to revert the state.

Comment: No good solutions so far...